# MaterCard Payment Gateway Complete Callback with Session id

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

I wonder if any one had build API with MPGS hosted checkout payment i parameters it's ok,and the transaction moves correctly and the receipt page shows, but the problem is when the receipt page shows to the customer there was no redirect to my website; I searched for how to make a callback:

complete callback done with :

1. create a checkout session using the create checkout session
   operation
2. pass session.id into checkout.configure ()
3. provide callback.complete function or url

the code to create a create a checkout session is :

```
curl https://switch.gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/51 \    
-d "apiOperation=CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION" \
-d "apiPassword=$PWD" \
-d "interaction.returnUrl=" \
-d "apiUsername=merchant." \
-d "merchant=" \
-d "order.id=" \
-d "order.amount=100.00" \
-d "order.currency=USD"
```

But I have no idea how to place it in the script above.

how can I solve it?

please advise ,

Answer (score 0):

The code to create a checkout session is an API call, which means that it shouldn't be passed in the script. The response of `Create Checkout Session` returns the `session.id` which you need to pass in the `Checkout.configure()` method of the script.

Comment: Please Help me to create checkout session .How can i call rest API to generate session.id

Comment: Gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/52/merchant/{merchantId}/session ..how can i integrate to create checkout session

Comment: What programming language are you using? For Node.js, the call would be: 
`var request = require('request');

var dataString = 'apiPassword=$PWD&interaction.returnUrl=&apiUsername=merchant.&merchant=&order.id=&order.amount=100.00&order.currency=USD';

var options = {
    url: 'https://switch.gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/51',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);`

Comment: i am using Asp.net .

Comment: You can create a similar API call in ASP.NET